# Firebase Authendication using LDAP

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My company owns Active Directory(AD) on Windows Server 2012, We need to integrate the AD with our web app developed and hosted on Firebase.

Company AD supports, LDAP to validate the user credentials.

I need help to get the approach to implement the same.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase does not natively support LADP or any third party OAuth provider. Instead we might need to create custom tokens for authentication. 
Custom token can be generated using firebase's built-in Admin SDK or we can also programmatically create custom tokens in any language using third-party JWT libraries.
Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/

Please refer the link for creating custom tokens:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens